# How to speed up (or memoize) a series of mutually recursive functions

Tags: haskell, memoization, mutual-recursion

I have a program which produces a series of functions `f` and `g` which looks like the following:

```
step (f,g) = (newF f g, newG f g)

newF f g x = r (f x) (g x)
newG f g x = s (f x) (g x)

foo = iterate step (f0,g0)
```

Where r and s are some uninteresting functions of `f x` and `g x`. I naively hoped that having `foo` be a list would mean that when I call the n'th `f` it will not recompute the (n-1)th `f` if it has already computed it (as would have happened if `f` and `g` weren't functions). Is there any way to memoize this without ripping the whole program apart (e.g. evaluating `f0` and `g0` on all relevant arguments and then working upward)?

Comment: Recomputing the n'th `f` repeatedly doesn't recompute the (n-1)'th `f` repeatedly... but remember, recomputing a function doesn't mean the same thing as recomputing the result of calling a function with an argument!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [Data.MemoCombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-memocombinators/0.4.3/doc/html/Data-MemoCombinators.html) useful (in the data-memocombinators package).

You don't say what argument types your `f` and `g` take --- if they both takes integral values then you would use it like this:

```
import qualified Data.MemoCombinators as Memo

foo = iterate step (Memo.integral f0, Memo.integral g0)
```

If required, you could memoise the output of each step as well

```
step (f,g) = (Memo.integral (newF f g), Memo.integral (newG f g))
```

I hope you don't see this as ripping the whole program apart.

---

In reply to your comment:

This is the best I can come up with. It's untested, but should be working along the right lines.

I worry that converting between `Double` and `Rational` is needlessly inefficient --- if there was a `Bits` instance for `Double` we could use `Memo.bits` instead. So this might not ultimately be of any practical use to you.

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.Ratio (numerator, denominator, (%))

memoV :: Memo.Memo a -> Memo.Memo (V a)
memoV m f = \(V x y z) -> table x y z
  where g x y z = f (V x y z)
        table = Memo.memo3 m m m g

memoRealFrac :: RealFrac a => Memo.Memo a
memoRealFrac f = Memo.wrap (fromRational . uncurry (%))
                           ((numerator &&& denominator) . toRational)
                           Memo.integral
```

---

A different approach.

You have

```
step :: (V Double -> V Double, V Double -> V Double)
     -> (V Double -> V Double, V Double -> V Double)
```

How about you change that to

```
step :: (V Double -> (V Double, V Double))
     -> (V Double -> (V Double, V Double))
step h x = (r fx gx, s fx gx)
  where (fx, gx) = h x
```

And also change

```
foo = (fst . bar, snd . bar)
  where bar = iterate step (f0 &&& g0)
```

Hopefully the shared `fx` and `gx` should result in a bit of a speed-up.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The only trouble I see with this approach is that `f` and `g` have type `V Double -> V Double` where `data V a = V a a a` and it's not exactly clear to me how I'd write a "`Memo.v`" or if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to memoize this without ripping the whole program apart (e.g. evaluating f0 and g0 on all relevant arguments and then working upward)?

This may be what you mean by "ripping the whole program apart", but here is a solution in which (I believe but can't test ATM) `fooX` can be shared.

```
nthFooOnX :: Integer -> Int -> (Integer, Integer)
nthFooOnX x = 
    let fooX = iterate step' (f0 x, g0 x)
     in \n-> fooX !! n

step' (fx,gx) = (r fx gx, s fx gx)

-- testing definitions:
r = (+)
s = (*)
f0 = (+1)
g0 = (+1)
```

I don't know if that preserves the spirit of your original implementation.